# I'm trying to make a for loop but it did not work (A little bit complex)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, discord.py, pycord

So I'm trying to make a 'for' loop In my discord bot. But It giving me errors in whatever I try.

The loop is for the embed.add_field function, Here's what I tried:

```py
for i in netres:
  embed.add_field(name=f"Email: {netres[0][i[0]]}", value=f"Password: {netres[1][i]}", inline=False)
```

if it can Help, netres = a c.fetchall from a db.
Here's netres:

```py
netres = c.fetchall()
```

The full traceback is:

````
Ignoring exception in command buy:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sidal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 124, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(arg)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sidal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 980, in _invoke
    await self.callback(ctx, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sidal\Desktop\sidtho\main.py", line 323, in buy
    embed.add_field(name=f"Email: {netres[0][i[0]]}", value=f"Password: {netres[1][i]}", inline=False)
                                   ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sidal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\bot.py", line 1114, in invoke_application_command  
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\sidal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 375, in invoke
    await injected(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\sidal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 132, in wrapped
    raise ApplicationCommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError: Application Command raised an exception: TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, 
not str```
````

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make the elements of tuples either an integer or slices. (if your requirement is string)

Comment: I did not correctly understand what you said. Can you please edit your answer and add more details ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).